# How to compute test/validation loss in pycaffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to compute the test loss in my own training loop in python. Calling `solver.test_nets[0].forward()` seems to update the `score` blob but not the `loss` one. Any idea how to get it updated?

I am using the following solver config:

```
net: "/tmp/tmp8ikb9sg2/train.prototxt"
test_net: "/tmp/tmp8ikb9sg2/test.prototxt"
test_iter: 1
test_interval: 2147483647
base_lr: 0.1
lr_policy: "fixed"
test_initialization: false
```

and train and test.prototxt are exactly the same except for the phase definition at the top of the file:

```
name: "pycaffenet"
state {
  phase: TRAIN  # set TEST in test.prototxt
}
...
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "output"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: What does the prototxt look like? Is there a `include' parameter that is restricting loss layer to only train phase?

Comment: @Prophecies I am not restricting the loss layer. I have added parts of the prototxt files in the description ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a different issue that what I thought. The `loss` blob was being updated but it remained the same because the weights of `solver.test_nets[0]` were not changing. It looks like they not automatically shared with `solver.net`. This can be done by simply calling:

```
solver.test_nets[0].share_with(solver.net)
```